# malloc allocating the same memory location to 2 pointers

Tags: c, pointers, memory-management, malloc

While writing `c` code I noticed that when I change the value associated with memory location pointed to by pointer x, it results in a change of value of the data pointed to by pointer y.

When I checked again I found that `malloc` is allocating overlapping regions of memory for to 2 different pointers. Why is this happening??

I have quite a few dynamically allocated variables in my code. So is it because there is a limit to the maximum amount of memory that can allocated by `malloc`?

The following is an output from my code. From the output you can see that `malloc` allocates overlapping memory regions to x and y.

```
size x:32 y:144 //total size allocated to x and y by malloc

//the memory locations allocated to each of the pointers

location x:0x7fb552c04d20 y:0x7fb552c04c70 

location x:0x7fb552c04d24 y:0x7fb552c04c8c

location x:0x7fb552c04d28 y:0x7fb552c04ca8

location x:0x7fb552c04d2c y:0x7fb552c04cc4

location x:0x7fb552c04d30 y:0x7fb552c04ce0

location x:**0x7fb552c04d34** y:0x7fb552c04cfc

location x:0x7fb552c04d38 y:0x7fb552c04d18

location x:0x7fb552c04d3c y:**0x7fb552c04d34**
```

The code i used for allocating memory is

```
int *x = (int *)malloc((DG_SIZE+1)*sizeof(int));
int *y = (int *)malloc(4*(DG_SIZE+2)*sizeof(int));

printf("\n size x:%d y:%d\n", (DG_SIZE+1)*sizeof(int), 4*(DG_SIZE+2)*sizeof(int));

int a = 0;
for(a = 0; a <= DG_SIZE; a++){
   printf("\n location x:%p y:%p\n",(x + a), (y + a*DG_SIZE + 0));
}
```

Comment: Post the code where you make the call to malloc

Comment: int *x = (int *)malloc((DG_SIZE+1)*sizeof(int));
int *y = (int *)malloc(4*(DG_SIZE+2)*sizeof(int));

Comment: And how about `x`? Paste the whole snippet that leads to the output.

Comment: No `free()`, no loop?

Comment: @JohnsPaul Also, don't cast the return of malloc.

Comment: Put that in the question. And show all your code. For example you still haven't even shown how `x` is allocated and how you are printing the output. You may be leaving out code which you think isn't relevant but the chances are that it really is (`malloc` is very very very unlikely to be doing the wrong thing).

Comment: How are you printing it?

Comment: Have you considered using `valgrind`?

Comment: @JohnsPaul Paste the entire snippet, with allocation, printing, and freeing of memory.

Comment: See [Do I cast the result of `malloc`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/4228131)

Comment: Post the code where you are printing the address. Generally, on windows `0x7f` is the location where system dlls are loaded. Although I am not sure on this. Can somebody confirm this ?

Comment: "when i change the value associated with memory location pointed to by pointer x" - How awesome it would be if *any* of the posted code actually *did that*. [Post an **MCVE**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: //the addresses were displayed using the following code :

int a = 0;
for(a = 0; a <= DG_SIZE; a++){
 printf("\n location x:%p y:%p\n",(x + a), (y + a*DG_SIZE + 0));
}

Comment: And show the code where you are writing using the pointers and how you are checking the value through the other pointer (my bet is that you are overflowing a buffer somewhere).

Comment: Hi,
I am really sorry for posting only small portions of the code. But I am working on a proprietary code and that is why i cant post all my code here. Also i tried the code without the cast and that returned the same output.

Comment: @AlanAu do i need to post the code that overwrites the the pointer? From the output it is clear that pointer x needs to have 32 bytes and and y needs 144 bytes. Also its can be seen that these 32 byte and 144 byte chunks have overlapping memory regions

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `y` block is wholly before the `x` block in memory. There's no overlap.

However your loop is printing out addresses from beyond the end of the `y` block, into the `y` column.

Specifically:

```
int *y = (int *)malloc(4*(DG_SIZE+2)*sizeof(int));
```

has allocated `36` ints, because `DG_SIZE` is `7` (based on your output).

But then you loop `a` from `0` to `7` and output `(y + a*DG_SIZE + 0)`. When `a == 6`, this gives `y + 42` which is beyond the end of the 36 ints allocated.

I guess you meant to output `y + a*4`, rather than `y + a*DG_SIZE`.